# Path name format - Windows - Python

Tags: python

I am working on a code that takes the path of a file and the reads it. 
The code is,

```
import sys
import os

user_input = input("Enter the path of your file: ")

assert os.path.exists(user_input), "I did not find the file at, "+str(user_input)
```

However, I am on a Windows machine in which, the path names come with a `\`, like, `C:\your\path\and\file.xlsx`

Each time I enter the file name to the prompt, I need to manually replace all `\` with `/` and then run the code.

Is there a solution such that I enter `C:\your\path\and\file.xlsx` but the code takes it as, `C:/your/path/and/file.xlsx`

Regards.

Comment: Look at using the `pathlib` module in the std lib, and create a `Path` object with the string.

Comment: You shouldn't be changing the \ to / at all. If the user inputs a valid path, you will be able to use it in your program as is. Backslashes only need to be escaped in *string literals*, not in *data*.

Comment: BTW, you should not use `assert` to validate data. `assert` is intended for validating the logic of your code. If you want to raise an exception on bad data, raise `ValueError`. Also, `str(user_input)` is redundant, `user_input` is already a string.

Comment: Are you by any chance using a Cygwin Python instead of a native Python?

Comment: @abarnert I am using Anaconda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pythons builtin `pathlib` like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

# No matter what slash you use in the input path
# I used Raw-Prefix 'r' here because \t would otherwise be interpreted as tab
path_a = Path(r"C:\Temp\test.txt)
path_b = Path(r"C:\Temp/test.txt)
path_c = Path(r"C:/Temp/test.txt)
path_d = Path(r"C:\\Temp\\test.txt)

print(path_a, path_b, path_c, path_d)
# all Paths will be the same:
# out >> C:\Temp\test.txt C:\Temp\test.txt C:\Temp\test.txt C:\Temp\test.txt
```

Furthermore you can also easily extend a given Path like this:

```
path_e = Path("C:\Temp")
extended_path = path_e / "Test"
print(extended_path)
# out >> C:\Temp\Test
```

So in your case simply do it like this:

```
import sys
import os

from pathlib import Path

user_input = input("Enter the path of your file: ")

file_path = Path(user_input)

if not os.path.exists(file_input):
     print("I did not find the file at, " + str(file_path))
```

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, when I use `\` in my path it just worked.  But for whatever reason if yours is not, here is a way to change backslash to slash.  One with a regex and one using replace:

```
import sys
import os
import re

user_input = input("Enter the path of your file: ")

#with a regex
user_input_regex = re.sub(r"\\", "/", user_input)
print(user_input_regex)

#using replace
user_input_replace = user_input.replace("\\","/")
print(user_input_replace)
```

I believe that replace is *slightly* faster but if you want to change other stuff (or just like using regex) the regex will probably offer more options down the road.  The key to this is the `\` needs to be escaped with a `\` since itself is an escape character.

Comment: Another option is `os.path.join(*user_input.split('\\'))`